# Change time stamp from unix to MM/DD/YYY in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I am looking for a way to transform my data to change the unix time stamp to DD/MM/YYY in given response format and return the same format back, I tried many ways to but I couldn't achieve what I wanted.

Here is the response format.

```
const mockResponse = 
  { identifier : 'something'
  , palette    : 'sev'
  , fus_config : 
    { dataSource: 
      { chart: { } 
      , dataset: 
        { data: 
          [ [ '1631212200000', 4.85, 27.49, 25] 
          , [ '1631212200000', 4.07, 25.39, 37] 
          , [ '1631212200000', 4.66, 24.48, 56] 
          , [ '1631212200000', 4.77, 24.05, 45] 
          ] 
  } } } }
```

I am expecting this to be transformed into this.

```
const mockResponse = 
  { identifier : 'something'
  , palette    : 'sev'
  , fus_config : 
    { dataSource: 
      { chart: { } 
      , dataset: 
        { data: 
          [ [ '12/13/1995', 4.85, 27.49, 25] 
          , [ '12/13/1995', 4.07, 25.39, 37] 
          , [ '12/13/1995', 4.66, 24.48, 56] 
          , [ '12/13/1995', 4.77, 24.05, 45] 
          ] 
  } } } }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to convert a single value of Unix time?

Comment: Yes, Like moment.unix(value).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

Comment: OK. Do you know how access attributes of a nested object? In your case, how to find the list for `data`?

Comment: I tried transforming the unix time stamp to this format format("MM/DD/YYYY"); 
using forEach but it's adding the index as an item i.e.  ['12/13/1995', 4.85, 27.49, 25, "0"],  ['12/13/1995', 4.85, 27.49, 25, "1"]

Comment: Add your code to your question. This will greatly improve your chances for a good answer.  Do **not** post code as comments - use [Edit] instead.